# Home made icon font renders Â character with icon glyphs on mobile browser

Tags: android, css, fonts, truetype, glyphicons

I created my own glyph icons as a True Type Font using FontLab Studio 5. I placed the nine vector paths into Unicode slots 00A1 through 00A9 and exported as a TTF. I embedded the font in my SCSS like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'iconfont';
    src: url('../../font/iconfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

*Update:* I have included a full set of web font formats to rule this out as a cause. Here is the new font embed:

```
src: url('../../font/jer-icon.eot');
src: url('../../font/jer-icon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../../font/jer-icon.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('../../font/jer-icon.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../../font/jer-icon.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../../font/jer-icon.svg#jer_iconsregular') format('svg');
```

Here is the SCSS code to place the icons:

```
$icon-one:   "\a1";
/* ... */
$icon-nine:  "\a9";
.element {
    &.before {
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: 'iconfont';
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 90vw;
        width: 90vw;
        content: $icon-one;
    }
}
```

*Update:* I should also include the meta tag that defines the character set.

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

On Chrome and Firefox on both PC and Mac it renders the glyphs exactly as expected. However on the Android Chrome browser, the glyphs are rendered with a preceding Â character. I took a screenshot of the two behaviors here:

[image: buggy view]

[image: correct view]

Comment: That sounds unrelated to the entire made-your-own-font, but more like it needs to be told to use UTF8 encoding. If the encoding of a webpage is not clear, it depends on the browser what you get.

Comment: Why are you  pretending real letters are icons? Put those icons in the PUA block, and use ligature rules for them instead, so that "smiley" turns into a smiley icon, etc? That said, [use WOFF](http://caniuse.com/#search=WOFF), not ttf. Every modern browser supports WOFF, whereas "not specifically packed for the web" formats are hit and miss depending on your audience.

Comment: Rad Lexus, I am setting the encoding through a Meta Tag: <meta charset="UTF-8" />

Comment: [Here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00A1/index.htm) - look at the UTF8 representation of `U+00A1`. It's `C2 A1`, exactly what you are seeing: `Â` plus the original character again. Mind you, it may be an error in the Chrome for Android as well - so try to test that.

Comment: Mike - I updated my fonts to include WOFF to rule that out.
RadLexus - It looks like you're on the right track, but I'm unclear on what I need to change. Do I need to alter my meta charset declaration, or the CSS character declarations?

Answer (score 1):

The character set defined in the Meta Tag was incorrect.

Wrong:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

Correct:

```
<meta charset="UTF8" />
```

Removing the dash in the charset attribute fixed the issue.

Thanks to Rad Lexus.